# How to Implement Rate Limiting in Azure Web Application Firewall(WAF)?

Tags: firewall, azure, rate-limiting, web-application-firewall

I am looking to implement global rate limiting to Azure WAF. I have created custom rate limiting rules but they are IP based. I know Azure DDoS protection provides a certain coverage limit. But my goal is to have a maximum limit of HTTP requests that I can serve before my application gets unstable or infrastructure cost goes too high. I do have things like maximum no. of K8 pods and their CPU limits defined, but this is an additional step to make sure everything is fine.

I feel this should be a common use case, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have contacted Azure support and they told that they dont have an option for global rate limiting.
The only viable solution that I have found so far is using NGINX Ingress controller explained in
https://medium.com/titansoft-engineering/rate-limiting-for-your-kubernetes-applications-with-nginx-ingress-2e32721f7f57. But this creates rate limits per NGINX Ingress pods and I have to have a new memcached pod to achieve global rate limiting with NGINX.

I am looking for possible solutions to achieve this.